# Twilio: Can I send an SMS from Twillio number to country which doesn't support it?

Tags: c#, .net, twilio

I've got the following problem - the Twilio numbers that can be genertated based in my country don't support SMS messaging, which I need. The workaround that I found was that if I generate a Twilio number based in a country which does support SMS messsaging(for example the UK) only then can I send an SMS from my Twilio number to my real phone number. I tried it like that and it works.

I was wondering if that's okay to do and if it will still work if I upgrade my account(currently I'm using a trial account). And will I be able to send SMS messages to any number in my country without having to do any verification like it's needed when I'm using my trial account.

Comment: This seems like a question better suited to asking the support group for the service, or a lawyer.  This isn't really a technical question, and any answer offered here wouldn't be legally binding.

Comment: I've upgraded my Twilio account a year ago and it works as expected. I can send SMS messages to any number. I've taken UK number from Twilio, since it has SMS messaging enabled (among other stuff).

Comment: @Jure Do you live the UK or you just used a number based in the UK, so that SMS messaging is enabled?

Comment: I do not live in UK. I've just used this number since its not expensive and it has SMS messaging enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr.Nicky

Once you upgrade your account , you will not be required to verify the numbers to call/message them . This is a limitation only on the [trial account.](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136107-How-does-Twilio-s-Free-Trial-work-)

About the coverage of numbers for messaging , you could use UK based numbers and send out sms to all supported destinations. The question on coverage is best addressed [here](https://www.twilio.com/sms/coverage)  . You can choose the country you want to have number in and then get all required information about the number coverage for messaging .

Hope this is useful.